# SELinux: Replacing selinux-default-policy (/etc/selinux/default/policy/policy.24) in Debian 6?

Tags: selinux

I am using Debian 6 with SELinux enabled.

On first time setup, I have installed `selinux-default-policy` package. So, policy at location `/etc/selinux/default/policy/policy.24` is used by SELinux.

Now, I want to build my own policy and make Debian to use my new policy instead of old policy (`/etc/selinux/default/policy/policy.24`).

To do this, I have downloaded the `refpolicy` from github.com and compiled using `make policy`. I have succeed at this point. After that, I have installed the same policy using `make install`. Now I could see that files are copied into location `/usr/share/selinux/policy/`.

I couldn't see any files like `policy.24` in `/usr/share/selinux/policy`. Please guide me to replace my `selinux-default-policy` with new one.

Comment: Your question is unrelated to programming and off-topic.

Comment: IMO this question is not unrelated to programming and off-topic. These SELinux policy files are programmable. If /etc/security/selinux/src/policy is present then replace it with newly compiled polcy file.

Comment: @anil, Thank you for your support! I have a directory like "/etc/selinux/refpolicy/src/" and it contains source only. And I have *.pp files in location "/usr/share/selinux/refpolicy". I couldn't find any file like policy.24, which is available in location /etc/selinux/default/policy/policy.24.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
make clean; make install; make load
```

Now you can see: `contexts`, `modules`, `seusers`, `policy` directories. Copy them and paste it into `/etc/selinux/default`. Then:

```
touch /.autorelabel ; reboot
```

You are done!